# Why such a difference in boot time?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have XP Pro SP3.

I have boot management software which allows me to regulate what boots and when.

There are no changes as to what is booting and when it is booting in the management software, but the boot time varies by as much as about 20 seconds.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: What boot management software? I'm sorry but this question is very vague. I wish I was a wizard and could read minds, but I am not :(

Comment: Keep trying :-). I was directed to "Soluto" free boot software on this forum. It times the boot and allows one to select every boot program and make a decision as to Keep, Remove or delay. It recommends actions, marking the ones that should NOT be removed as well as offers suggestions.

Thanks,
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't compare one boot to another. In order to any sort of statistical analysis, you really need a minimum of 20-50 boots.

The fact is, this can be anything in the background from applications performing updates in the background, Windows doing file checking or simply and sometimes it can be something such as temperature making a difference on certain components.

The most common cause I found was down to the hard drive, on 30+ scans of standard commercial grade drives, doing back to back performance scans can show a 5-10% performance difference...

There are just so many reasons it could be and it is really hard to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

By boot management software, do you mean something like [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/software.php?page=2&show=startdelay)?

A question to ask is : when do you consider the computer as "booted up"? When the desktop appears?

Using a tool like Startup Delayer means that all the I/O needed to load the startup programs are spread in a longer period. By having less programs load together at the start of the normal loading of startup program by Windows, the desktop appears faster, giving the impression of a faster boot.

Comment: My program is similar to this. Please see my comment on John T's comment. The program times "boot" and tells me when it is finished.

Thanks,
Regards,